# Histogram improvement or to plot histogram in 3D

Tags: pgfplots

I have created this histogram! I wanna ask:

1. Can I further improve it as at one "normalized frequency, 41" I have two "frequency shift values, 4 and 11"?
2. Is it possible to plot such histogram in 3D, so that the overlapped bars can be easily viewed? Thanks

```
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \centering
  \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
    height=10cm,
    width=13cm,
    enlarge y limits=false,
    axis lines*=left,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=100,
     legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},
        anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
        ylabel={Frequency shift \%},
        xlabel={Normalized frequency \%},
        symbolic x coords={41,41,54,54,57,59,59,67,67,67,67, 73, 73,79,79,81,81,90,90,99,99,100,100},
     xtick=data,
        nodes near coords,
    every node near coord/.append style={
        anchor=mid west,
        rotate=70
    }
    ]
    \addplot coordinates {(41,11) (41,4) (54,22) (54,5) (57,2) (59,5) (59,1) (67,40) (67,6) (67,8) (67,1) (73,4) (73,1) (79,64) (79,6) (81,16) (81,1) (90,93) (90,6) (99,55) (99,1) (100,100) (100,3)};
    \legend{Crack 3.2mm};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]